# How to access constructor of another class in java?

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor, overloading

I have a superclass called "Question". I have two subclasses which are derived from it, called "QuestionSA" (short answer) and "QuestionTF" (true/false).

This is what QuestionSA looks like:

```
public class QuestionSA extends Question {

private static char[] givenAnswer;

// ========================================================
// Name: constructor
// Input: the type of question, the level,
// the question and answer, as strings
// Output: none
// Description: overloaded constructor that feeds data
// ========================================================
QuestionSA(String type, String level, String question, String answer) {
    this.type = type;
    this.level = level;
    this.text = question;
    this.answer = answer;
}
```

I need to access the constructor in QuestionSA from QuestionTF. I've done it in C++ like this:

```
QuestionTF::QuestionTF(string type, string level, string question, string answer)
: QuestionSA(type, level, question, answer) {}
```

How can I do this in Java?

Comment: Can you also add the class QuestionTF?

Comment: I have to edit to clarify. I knew that this naming indicates that this is child class, but I had to check it double.

Comment: Why is `givenAnswer` static?

Answer (score 3):

If `QuestionTF` is subclass for `QuestionSA` you can access it's constructor using `super` keyword.

```
 QuestionTF(String type, String level, String question, String answer) {
     super(type, level, question, answer);
 }
```

If not, you cannot use subclass of your parent class constructors for creating new object.

Comment: As is understand is QuestionSA not a super class of QuestionTF

Comment: Using initializating list in c++ indicates that is sublcass, isn't it?

Comment: Not exactly, both QuestionSA and QuestionTF are the same level derived classes of Question. QuestionSA is not a super class of QuestionTF, or vice versa.

Comment: As in my answer, in that situation you cannot use constructors for creating object like that

Comment: @Dima If QuestionSA is not a superclass of QuestionTF, then your  C++ is broken and makes no sense.  That being the case, it's impossible to tell what you're asking for the Java equivalent of.

Answer (score 3):

Constructor is being called by JVM during creation an object of a class. So if you want to call a constructor of a class, you need to create an object of that class.
If you want to call constructor of a parent class from child class, u can call super() in the first line of child constructor.

Comment: So do you mean to say that if I create an instance of the QuestionSA class in the QuestionTF class, then whatever arguments I pass in for the constructor of QuestionTF, will be passed into the constructor of QuestionSA? This is the entire reason I did this in C++.